# Azure Durable Function fails to start after going idle (Intermittent)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

Every so often, we're faced with the intermittent issue of a Durable Function not starting up after going idle (Consumption plan).

Looking at the logs we see that it refers to a DI issue and/or failing to start in the:

```
ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs
```

Not so happy developer here, we're struggling to diagnose the issue! No detail in any MS documentation, or many reports of the problem.

Full trace below:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException : Assembly with same name is already loaded

  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromPath(IntPtr ptrNativeAssemblyLoadContext,String ilPath,String niPath,ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)

  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath(String assemblyPath)

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.b__0(AssemblyName assemblyName) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\DependencyInjection\ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 116

  at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String asmName,Func`2 assemblyResolver,Boolean throwOnError,StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

  at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver,Func`4 typeResolver,Boolean throwOnError,Boolean ignoreCase,StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

  at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName,Func`2 assemblyResolver,Func`4 typeResolver,Boolean throwOnError,Boolean ignoreCase,StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

  at System.Type.GetType(String typeName,Func`2 assemblyResolver,Func`4 typeResolver,Boolean throwOnError,Boolean ignoreCase)

  at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetExtensionsStartupTypesAsync() at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\DependencyInjection\ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 113

  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ScriptStartupTypeLocator.GetStartupTypes() at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\DependencyInjection\ScriptStartupTypeLocator.cs : 55

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.WebJobsBuilderExtensions.UseExternalStartup(IWebJobsBuilder builder,IWebJobsStartupTypeLocator startupTypeLocator,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsBuilderExtensions.cs : 167

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.UseScriptExternalStartup(IWebJobsBuilder builder,ScriptApplicationHostOptions applicationHostOptions,ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,IExtensionBundleManager extensionBundleManager,IMetricsLogger metricsLogger) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 237

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context,IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 114

  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WebJobsHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__1(HostBuilderContext context,IServiceCollection services) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\WebJobsHostBuilderExtensions.cs : 47

  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()

  at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()

  at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DefaultScriptHostBuilder.BuildHost(Boolean skipHostStartup,Boolean skipHostConfigurationParsing) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DefaultScriptHostBuilder.cs : 59

  at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebJobsScriptHostService.UnsynchronizedStartHostAsync(ScriptHostStartupOperation activeOperation,Int32 attemptCount,JobHostStartupMode startupMode) at C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\WebJobsScriptHostService.cs : 234
```

Any help will be super helpful.

**//Further Investigation**

Finally managed to find further details using app insights:

Message:

```
Method not found: 'Void DurableTask.AzureStorage.AzureStorageOrchestrationServiceSettings.set_FetchLargeMessageDataEnabled(Boolean)'.
```

Failed method:

```
DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.DryIocAdapter+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<RegisterDescriptor>b__0
```

With the above in mind, it appears that an in-built IoC container is failing to register?

Comment: please raise this in the official Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension

Comment: Hi @ThiagoCustodio thanks for your comment. I'll certainly move this over... SO is always my default.